# Intersection of subschemes of the (punctured) spectrum of regular local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be either the spectrum, or the punctured spectrum of a Noetherian regular local ring (by punctured spectrum I mean Spec$(R)\setminus \{\mathfrak m\}$ where $\mathfrak m$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$ )  . Let $d=\dim X$.

If $U,V$ are non-empty subschemes of $X$ with $\dim U + \dim V \ge d$ , then is it necessarily true that $U \cap V$ is non-empty ?

If this is not true in general, then what if we also assume both $U,V$ are open or both $U,V$ are closed ?

When $U,V$ are closed in the spectrum of a local ring , then $U\cap V$ must be non-empty because for any two proper ideals $I,J$ of a local ring, $I+J$ is also proper ... also if both $U,V$ are open in Spec$(R)$  then also we're done since Spec$(R)$ is irreducible so any two non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection ... I'm not sure what happens in other cases though like if one of them is open and the other is closed  ...

Motivation: since in many ways, the punctured spectrum of a regular local ring behaves like $\mathbb P^n_k$ and for $\mathbb P^n_k$ it is indeed true that for subschemes $U,V$ with $\dim U +\dim V \ge n$ implies $U \cap V$ is non-empty, hence my motivation for asking this question ...

Comment: -1 for a lack of research effort on the first question: have you tried any examples? You should be able to find counterexamples _very_ quickly.

Comment: @KReiser: yes, only with regular schemes, one can find counterexamples, even in the affine case, since two proper ideals can add up to give the whole ring ... however, that can't happen in affine local case with closed subschemes , so I've suitably modified the question ...

Comment: Why not just take $R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]_{(x_1,\ldots,x_d)}$ whose punctured spectrum is the prime ideals other than the unique maximal ideal $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ ? With $d=2$ then $V(x_1)\cap V(x_2) = V(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: @reuns: I think that doesn't work since $\dim V(x_i)=0$ in the punctured spectrum, so the dimension condition is not satisfied ...

Comment: Why $\dim V(x_i) =0$ ?

Comment: @reuns: with $d=2$, after you localise, if I'm not mistaken, $\dim V(x_i)=\dim R - ht (x_i)= 2-1=1$ (in a regular local ring , for any prime ideal $P$, $\dim V(P)(=\dim (R/P))=\dim R - ht (P) $), so when you view $V(x_i)$ in the punctured spectrum, the dimension drops by $1$ giving you dimension $V(x_i)$ in the punctured spectrum is $0$  ...

Comment: To me $k[x_1,x_2]_{(x_1,x_2)} / (x_1)$ has a chain of two prime ideals : $(0) \subset (x_2)$ so its Krull dimension is $1$, and the Krull dimension of the coordinate ring of an affine variety over a field $k$ is also the size of a transcendental basis over $k$ which stays the same in localizations (the dimension decreases in the quotient rings)

Comment: @reuns:  yes you're right it does have dimension $1$ (same as I said)  but that's in the spectrum, not in the punctured spectrum ..

Comment: So the Krull dimension is $1$ not $0$. If you substract 1 to all the dimensions because of the puncture (I don't see why you'd do it) then sure your claim holds.

Comment: @reuns: in the punctured spectrum you don't have $(x_2)$ in the coordinate ring any more ... $(x_2)$ in the coordinate ring is precisely $(x_1,x_2)/(x_1)$ which is what you're throwing out when you puncture the spectrum

Comment: @reuns: yes ... and remember your proposed counterexample was for punctured spectrum, which as you can see doesn't work since the dimension condition doesn't hold ...

Comment: @reuns: I guess what you're missing is that $V(x_1) \cap X$ , where $X$ is the punctured spectrum, doesn't have the prime ideal $(x_1, x_2)$ anymore ... so you can never have a chain of length $1$ in the punctured spectrum ... so by the standard definition of Krull dimension of a Topological space, the dimension is $0$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, one asks for a result like $U,V$ must intersect if something is true about their dimensions when $U,V$ are both closed inside some irreducible space - for instance, without requiring that they're closed, if they're both contained in lower-dimensional closed subvarieties and these subvarieties have no common components, you can often just delete the intersection points from one of $U$ or $V$ without changing anything about the circumstances of the problem. (The case of $U,V$ both open is trivial: a space is irreducible iff any two open subsets intersect, and any regular noetherian local ring is a domain, hence has irreducible spectrum, and any open subset of an irreducible space is again irreducible, so the punctured spectrum is again irreducible.)

In the case that $U,V$ are both closed, you know that they must intersect inside the punctured spectrum - there's only one closed point and every closed subset contains it, so every pair of closed subsets must intersect. This lets us get at the problem for the punctured spectrum in much the same manner as we treat intersections in projective space via the affine cone. The same proof will apply here - I leave it to you to verify the details.

Comment: For closed subschemes in the punctured spectrum case, I guess the only thing I'm thinking is why can't it happen that we have two ideals $I,J$ of $R$ such that $\mathfrak m$ is the only prime ideal above $I+J$ ? This will happen iff $V(I)\cap V(J)=\{\mathfrak m \}$  iff $\dim R/(I+J)=0 $ ... I'm not sure whether this would contradict the dimension condition or not ... also this answer of yours doesn't address the question of what happens when one of $U,V$ is open and the other is closed ...

Comment: Now that I think about it more closely, for any ideal $I$ of a Noetherian ring $R$ of finite dimension , there is a prime ideal $P$ lying above $I$ such that $\dim R/I=\dim R/P$. So by Serre's theorem, in a regular local ring, for any ideals $I,J$ , we should always have $\dim R/I + \dim R/J \le \dim R$ ... now my dimension condition for the  punctured spectrum states that $\dim (R/I) -1 + \dim (R/J) -1 \ge \dim R -1$, so $\dim (R/I)  + \dim (R/J) \ge \dim R +1$ , which is never true ... Please let me know if I'm saying this right or not ...

Comment: So my claim about closed subschemes of punctured spectrum is vacuously true ...

Comment: Again, asking about the case when $U$ is open and $V$ is closed is a bit silly: just remove $V$ from $U$ and then they don't intersect. You want to ask about $U,V$ closed.

Comment: Your second comment is very puzzling to me. Your claim is not correct: consider $R=k[x,y,z]$ with $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$. Then $\dim R/I+\dim R/J = 2+2=4 \not\leq 3= \dim R$ and all of this is preserved upon going to the localization at the origin. I don't understand what you're up to here.

Comment: Next, you need to think more carefully about what's going on in the punctured case - suppose you have closed $U,V$. Then saying that their dimensions in punctured spec add to be greater than the dimension of the punctured spec means that their dimensions in the nonpunctured spectrum add to be at least more than the dimension of the nonpunctured spectrum, so their intersection has all irred components of dimension at least one if they're nonempty. But their intersection is nonempty by the previous discussion, and being at least 1-d means that there's a point which survives after the puncture.

Comment: $U,V$ should be irreducible in that last comment.

Comment: Agh right indeed Serre's lemma is valid when $l_R(R/(P+Q)) <\infty$ i.e. $V(P+Q)=V(P) \cap V(Q)=\{\mathfrak m \}$ ... in fact that gives a proof for the closed subset case of the punctured spectrum ... also I don't quite see why asking about $U$ open and $V$ closed is silly ... the trick you suggest of removing $V$ from $U$ might not work as we've to make sure my dimension condition is satisfied (if such a simple trick works then we wouldn't have the fact for $\mathbb P^n_k$ )

Comment: If $U$ is open and irreducible, removing a proper closed subset does not change the dimension. Remember, the fact for $\Bbb P^n$ is stated for two CLOSED subvarieties. This is what you should be trying to emulate.